# Xmove is unable to connect to X11 server via SSH X forwarding

Tags: ssh, x11, xauth

I have a LAN where a windows machine running Cygwin (XWin server) is used to connect to a Linux host via SSH with trusted X forwarding. I connect with

```
$ ssh -Y user@linuxhost
```

without any issues and X11 applications from linuxhost display their windows on the Cygwin machine.

What I'm trying to achieve now is make apps on linuxhost persistent despite windows machine reboots etc. To achieve this, I have installed `xmove` to linuxhost and started an app on it locally:

```
$ xmove &
$ DISPLAY=:1 leafpad
```

This command opens a new window on linuxhost's own X server, so `xmove` kind of works.
However, when I'm connecting via SSH as usual and trying to move this window to Cygwin's X server, I get an error:

```
$ ssh -Y user@linuxhost
user@linuxhost's password:*****
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
$ xauth list
linuxhost/unix:0 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE blablabla0
linuxhost/unix:1 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE blablabla1
linuxhost/unix:10 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE blablabla10
$ xmovectrl -moveall linuxhost:10
```

At this point `xmovectrl` just hangs, and no windows are forwarded to windows machine.

So, is the way I attempt to use `xmove` the right way to achieve X apps persistence? Did anyone have a working `xmove` setup procedure he could share? Any pointers?

Comment: Have you considered installing `freenx-server` on your Linux system?  You would be able to connect and have a complete desktop session (akin to connecting to a Windows system with RDP).  If you disconnect, all of your open applications are still running in the NX session, just reconnect and they're always there.

Comment: Is it possible to migrate freenx session to a linuxhost's X server once the remote session disconnects? Wouldn't this incur too much overhead?

Comment: If I understand correctly, with `freenx` all screen activity will go through SSH tunnel even if both client and server are on the same machine, whereas `xmove` can migrate windows from a remote session to local X server, eliminating SSH completely.